# Using RequireJS with Mocha and SquireJS on node

Tags: node.js, requirejs, mocha.js, squirejs

I am trying to use RequireJS in node, and found difficulties with path issues.

Here is a simple foo method that returns "foo"

```
$ cat src/foo.js 

define([], function() {

    var foo = function() {
        return "foo";
    };

    return { foo:foo};
});
```

Here is bar that requires foo, but it works only when specifying relative path. Is that how it's supposed to be?

```
$ cat src/bar.js
define(['./foo.js'], function(foo) {

    var bar = function() {
        return foo.foo().replace("foo","bar");
    };

    return { bar : bar };
});
```

Things get much trickier in the mocha test:

1. Loading foo and bar requires __dirname workarounds.
2. The async loading of bar fails (see test 3 and 4).
3. Importing Squire needs exact path, since it is installed using npm install, but does not conform to the standard node require syntax and does not include the amdefine workaround:

Here is the test code:

```
$ cat test/footests.js 
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
var chai = requirejs("chai");
var should = chai.should();
var Squire = requirejs(__dirname + "/../node_modules/squirejs/src/Squire.js");

describe('when calling foo.foo()', function () {
   it('should return "foo"', function() {
        var foo = requirejs(__dirname + "/../src/foo.js");
        foo.foo().should.equal("foo");
    });
});

describe('when calling bar.bar()', function () {
    var bar = requirejs(__dirname + "/../src/bar.js");
    it('should return "bar"', function() {
        bar.bar().should.equal("bar");
    });
});

describe('when calling bar.bar() with async requirejs', function () {
    it('should return "bar"', function(done) {
        requirejs(__dirname + "/../src/bar.js", function(bar) {
            bar.bar().should.equal("bar");
            done();
        })
    });
});
describe('when mocking foo.foo() and calling bar.bar()', function () {
    it('should return "barbar"', function(done) {
        var injector = new Squire();
        var fooMock = {
            foo : function() {
                return "foofoo"; /* instead of just foo */
            }
        };
        injector
          .mock('./foo.js', fooMock)
          .require(__dirname + "/../src/bar.js", function(bar) {
              bar.bar().should.equal("barbar");
              done();
          });
    });
});
```

I've setup a reproduction on github https://github.com/itaifrenkel/node-requirejs-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

1. Don't put `.js` at the end of module names. Adding `.js` tells RequireJS to bypass the normal module name resolution. (There are some cases where you *want* the extension but these should be cases where you can say why you need it.)
2. RequireJS in Node can take a configuration, just like when you use it in a browser. This eliminates the need to duplicate paths all over the place.
3. RequireJS can load packages with the `packages` setting.
4. Don't load Node modules with RequireJS when there's no need for it. (For instance, `chai` does not need to be loaded with RequireJS.)

If I modify `bar.js` to drop the `.js` extension from its lone dependency and use the following test file, it works:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname + "/../src",
    packages: [
        {
            name: "squirejs",
            location: "../node_modules/squirejs",
            main: "src/Squire"
        }
    ]
});
var chai = require("chai");
var should = chai.should();
var Squire = requirejs("squirejs");

describe('when calling foo.foo()', function () {
   it('should return "foo"', function() {
        var foo = requirejs("foo");
        foo.foo().should.equal("foo");
    });
});

describe('when calling bar.bar()', function () {
    var bar = requirejs("bar");
    it('should return "bar"', function() {
        bar.bar().should.equal("bar");
    });
});

describe('when calling bar.bar() with async requirejs', function () {
    it('should return "bar"', function(done) {
        requirejs(["bar"], function(bar) {
            bar.bar().should.equal("bar");
            done();
        });
    });
});
describe('when mocking foo.foo() and calling bar.bar()', function () {
    it('should return "barbar"', function(done) {
        var injector = new Squire();
        var fooMock = {
            foo : function() {
                return "foofoo"; /* instead of just foo */
            }
        };
        injector
          .mock('./foo', fooMock)
          .require(["bar"], function(bar) {
              bar.bar().should.equal("barfoo");
              done();
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I've seen tests that do not need the requirejs header. What changes are needed to clean the test from the requirejs header and do with define(['chai','squirejs'],function(chai,Squire) {...}) ?
 I get "define is not defined" ofcourse.

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to with the expression "requirejs header".

Comment: I mean cut paste "var requirejs;requirejs.config" to another common file, and start the test file with define(['chai','should','squire'],function(chai,should,Squire){});